# Implementing concurrency in Websphere based application

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, websphere, executorservice

We are developing a Java EE Web Application which is deployed on Websphere Web server. Currently, there is a requirement for concurrent execution to speed-up the response time. So among the below choices, which and why will be a better selection?

1. Using `ExecutorService`
2. Using `Managed Executor Service` 
   (What are the basic usage & implementation difference between these above two methods)
3. Any other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc for ManagedExecutorService makes the difference pretty clear:

> A ManagedExecutorService extends the Java™ SE ExecutorService to
>   provide methods for submitting tasks for execution in a Java™ EE
>   environment. Implementations of the ManagedExecutorService are
>   provided by a Java™ EE Product Provider. Application Component
>   Providers use the Java Naming and Directory Interface™ (JNDI) to
>   look-up instances of one or more ManagedExecutorService objects using
>   resource environment references. ManagedExecutorService instances can
>   also be injected into application components through the use of the
>   Resource annotation.

You should simply use the spec-defined EE concurrency utilities (including ManagedExecutor).

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/asyncbns/concepts/casb_concurrency.html